# SQL query in one table in 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have for example this database table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` 
(
    `refid` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `myrefid` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `user` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`refid`,`myrefid`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `docs` (`refid`, `myrefid`, `user`) 
VALUES ('1', '5', 'user1'),
       ('2', '1', 'user2'),
       ('9', '3', 'user3'),
       ('8', '3', 'user4');
       ('4', '3', 'user5');
       ('4', '8', 'user6');
```

I want to write a query where I get user2 and user6 because from user2 is the myrefid (value) same like from user1 refid (value) and from user6 is the myrefid (value) same like from user4 refid (value)

How can I write this query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` and check you condition

> ```
> SELECT 
>     `user`
> FROM `docs` d WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `docs` WHERE `refid` = d.`myrefid`)
> ```
>
> ```
> | user  |
> | :---- |
> | user2 |
> | user6 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c07fd483714ed86a9874eb82a7fde779)*